# No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*catkin_make* suddenly started to fail with the following error in **Fedora 20**:

```
[ 97%] make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so', needed by XYZ
```

*yum provides* gives:

```
1:qt-devel-4.8.5-10.fc20.i686 : Development files for the Qt toolkit
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libQtWebKit_debug.so

1:qt-devel-4.8.5-10.fc20.x86_64 : Development files for the Qt toolkit
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libQtWebKit_debug.so
```

So, both libraries are already installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200246/no-rule-to-make-target-%60/usr/lib64/libqtwebkit_debug.so/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a Fedora bug in VTK packaging and was fixed: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/1080781

Just update `vtk-devel` to the latest version.

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0